# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined' with `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors = false`

Tags: typescript

Recently I toggle TSConfig property [suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors) from `true` to `false` to force me to write better code, but I encounter this issue that is the only one I wasn't able to fix.

It's a simple form with a checkbox and a text input that will add a `true` to `filters` in case that the checkbox is checked or delete the property if it existed in case it is `false`. The search string is also added if there is any text, if not is deleted as with the checkbox property.

```
interface UserFilters {
    searchText?: string;
    hasAction?: boolean;
}

const filters = {} as UserFilters;

function filterUsers(filterName: keyof UserFilters, value: string | boolean | undefined) {
    if (value) filters[filterName] = value; // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
    else delete filters[filterName];
}
```

I did this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoDFgBtJTrIDeAUMhcpnFAgBYAqEAHmAPwBcVYUoA5gG5ylOnHQBBBGGAB7EJ2QAjGTNwQ4IIQF9SpBHPRhkMPASIBeEluRi0mKDnzR0Q0jACuIKbJDHT0DGcAChMnKAA5OABbCC4AawgATxkYO2x-QgAaZAA3OFx3WO5eED5kAB8lFTUNCuRPABMIExAIBoBKEmEKYFSgvIKITtCzAG0R6EiYgF1kSwHCoUpkCFxMZCa1SD8w9HGMqYhp7SA) to show you the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `filterUsers` is that `filterName` and `value` are not related in any way, so for example `filterUsers('searchText', true)` would be a valid call. That's also why you can't make the types work in the body.

You can fix it by making the function generic:

```
function filterUsers<K extends keyof UserFilters>(
  filterName: K,
  value: UserFilters[K],
) {
  if (value) filters[filterName] = value
  else delete filters[filterName]
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/Narypm)

Comment: Oh I see, that's a really good answer, thanks for explaining it so well @Oblosys!